# Perl paragraph generator losing punctuation

Tags: perl

I need to generate paragraph(s) of random text. At the end of each sentence I'd like to add punctuation, and as a sentence the starting word should be capitalized. I have this so far:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl -w -U
use English;

sub cWord {
  return "C";
}
sub lWord {
  return "l";
}

  my $paras = 3;
  my $limit = 15;
  my ($w, $wMax);
  my @words;

  my $pMax = 3 + rand $paras;
  for (my $p=0; $p<$pMax; $p++)
  {
    $wMax = 5 + rand $limit;
    for ($w=0; $w<=$wMax; $w++)
    {
      push @words, (!$w ? &cWord : &lWord) . ($w == $wMax ? '. ' : '');
    }
  }

  print join ' ', @words;

  print "\n";

  print @words;
```

It seems the '.' sentence trailer is getting clipped?

```
2% perl ./f.pl
C l l l l l l l l l C l l l l l l l l l l C l l l l l l l l l l l C l l l l l l l l l l 
l l C l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l C l l l l l l l l

ClllllllllCllllllllllClllllllllllCllllllllllllCllllllllllllllllllCllllllll2%
```

Comment: `$w` will never equal `$wMax` because you are setting `$wMax` to a random float value between 5 and 20. You may want `int rand $limit`.

Comment: Always use strict and warnings (not -w).

Comment: Arrgh; darn floats; I think that's it!  Yup; wrapping rand result with int() did the trick: `C l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l.  C l l l l l l l l l.  C l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l.  C l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l. Cllllllllllllllll. Clllllllll. Clllllllllllllllll. Cllllllllllllllllll.`
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have forgot to do type conversion

```
int(rand $limit);
```

this should fix your issue. 
without this your code will never execute for

```
$w == $wMax
```